# Right way to force uniqueness on a join model? (has_many :through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, unique, has-many-through

I have a parent/child relationship via our users table, with models as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Parents relationship
  has_many :children_parents, :class_name => "ParentsChild", :foreign_key => "child_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :parents, :through => :children_parents

  # Children relatiopnship
  has_many :parents_children, :class_name => "ParentsChild", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :children, :through => :parents_children
  ...
end
```

And in parents_child.rb:

```
class ParentsChild < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "User"

end
```

Right now, it is possible in our "add children" form (just using vanilla nested attributes) to add the same user as a child multiple times for parents.  I am not sure what the 'right' way to go about forcing uniqueness in the ParentsChild relationship, although I am leaning towards a unique index on `(parent_id, child_id)` at the database layer (using a migration of course).

I am sure I could also enforce uniqueness constraints in the UsersController::update method, but would prefer to avoid changing that code (right now it doesn't reference parents/children at all, thanks to nested attributes in the form/model) if possible.  I am most concerned with making sure we use the "proper" solution.  What is the 'right' or 'rails' way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using has_many :through, you can specify :uniq as an option, like this:

```
  has_many :parents, :through => :children_parents, :uniq => true
```

Comment: Definitely should have looked at the simplest possible solution first. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! I spend so long fiddling with this, your answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: or in rails 4, `has_many :parents, -> { uniq }, :through => :children_parents`

Comment: is good to note that this does not stop creating repeated records in join table, but it does return uniq records

Comment: also, I get `DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use distinct instead)`